# signal SIGABRT Error when trying to run xcode 5.0 app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode5, sigabrt

Sorry to ask, I have tried everything I have read online, but I keep getting the SIGABRT Error when I try to run an app.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Error code comes up beside the         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
 line.

The debugger just states

```
2013-10-18 10:29:45.270 Black History Month[733:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x903f770> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14a3052 0xea3d0a 0x14a2f11 0x9b3032 0x924f7b 0x924eeb 0x93fd60 0x23291a 0x14a4e1a 0x140e821 0x23146e 0x233010 0x1314a 0x13461 0x127c0 0x21743 0x221f8 0x15aa9 0x138dfa9 0x14771c5 0x13dc022 0x13da90a 0x13d9db4 0x13d9ccb 0x122a7 0x13a9b 0x2712 0x2685)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I have tried producing a couple different apps and always get this error so cannot release, I have now tried a simple uiwebview app and the same thing keeps happening.  I have tried running on many different deployement targets with no successful outcomes.

I have tried resetting the simulator, restarting both xcode the simulator, and computer multiple times, turned off auto layout for the xib file.  No luck.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the reason is given. there is a attempt to access the 'view' property on the UIApplication object. it doesn't have that property.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with Xcode. Your application has thrown a run time exception. Since the exception is not caught anywhere it is poped upto main. Set an exception to [All Breakpoint](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) to figure out whats wrong. If your app worked in Xcode 4 then check the iOS deployment target. I suspect it has to do with iOS 7 which is default target in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error. After spending so much time, I found how to fix it. First of all go the console and see where is the error (mine was related to storyboards and its code) The way I fixed my error was by going in story board. Below the iPhone screen, there will be small yellow button. Right click on it and you will see that is causing error. Delete(x) it if there is yellow error sign.

If this does not fix your error then try to make new project and then replace its blank files with old files of your old project. I had same error in very beginning and by doing this program run without any error.

Other people suggests by restarting your laptop and running it again, reseting the iOS simulator, or changing iOS debugger (however this does not work in latest x code since there is only one debugger)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

From the error message

> [<UIApplication 0x903f770> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key view.

one can see that you try to set the `view` property on an instance of `UIApplication`,
but `UIApplication` does not have a `view` property.

To find the point where the error occurs, set a breakpoint on
"All Objective-C Exceptions".

Answer (score 0):

> I also had this error. After spending so much time, I found how to fix it. First >of all go the console and see where is the error (mine was related to storyboards >and its code) The way I fixed my error was by going in story board. Below the >iPhone screen, there will be small yellow button. Right click on it and you will >see that is causing error. Delete(x) it if there is yellow error sign.

I would +1 Viraj's answer, but I don't have the reputation. I can verify that in a Swift project in X-Code 6, this solution works. My problem was:

*My app ran great on the initial view controller and on the 2nd screen, but upon trying to load the third view controller, my app would crash and return the "SIGABRT" error.*

**The Fix** was indeed to go to the screen where my app was crashing, right click on the yellow icon (which is ABOVE the view in my version of X Code). I had two IB Outlets assigned to views, which did not have connections to the code. I did not need them too (they were old), so I deleted both from within the Outlets inspector in the right sided attributes inspector.